# Can't seem to push Firestore data to Dialogflow

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am having some trouble pulling some data back to Dialogflow from Firestore. I can console log the value but it is not getting pushed to agent.add()

I have a collection of products with each doc containing product information:

Product > firebaseId >

```
{
name: "Coca Cola",
price: 1.00
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  
  function readFromDb (agent) {
    const prodName = agent.parameters.product;
    
    const dialogflowAgentDoc = db.collection('dialogflow').where('name', '==', prodName);
    

    return dialogflowAgentDoc.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
          agent.add('The price of ' + doc.data().name + ' is ' + doc.data().price + ' dollars!');
        }
        return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
      }).catch(() => {
        agent.add('Error reading entry from the Firestore database.');
        
      });
  }


  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('priceCheck', readFromDb);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

UPDATE: The type error is no longer showing up

But the request is timing out... I tried to do the same with the RTDB and can't seem to run a query at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here, which may be hiding what the true error is.

**Why do I get a TypeError?**

Because the `.catch()` is trying to be called on the result of your `snapshot.forEach()`, which doesn't return anything. It probably should be moved one level out - that it be called on the result of the `product.then()`, which is a Promise.

**Why is the console.log() called, but not the agent.add()?**

I think `agent.add()` is being called, but because there is a TypeError, an exception is being called so there is an implicit Promise rejection. Because there is a Promise rejection, the Dialogflow Handler doesn't actually add any of the replies.

It does look like your call to `agent.add()` is being done correctly, at least at a glance.

Comment: I get these errors: dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Error: No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE at WebhookClient.send_ (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:488:13) at promise.then (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:306:38) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

When I check diagnostic info:

Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED. is the error it is giving me